# newcommand and math environment

Tags: math-mode

So I've created a latex `command` using `newcommand`. This is its definition

```
\newcommand{\twopartdef}[3]
{
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        #1 & \mbox{if } #2 \\
        #3 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\right
}
```

But when I try to use the command with this example

```
f$(x)$ = \twopartdef{$\lbrace \alpha \rbrace}{$x >$ 10}{\lbrace \beta \rbrace}
```

Latex tells me that it added the symbol `$` because it was unmatched..

What am doing wrong? What corrections should I make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are writing this entire `array` construction in a display math environment (since it's at least two lines in height. As such, you don't need any math-switching delimiters inside your usage:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\twopartdef}[3]{%
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      #1 & \mbox{if } #2 \\
      #3 & \mbox{otherwise}
    \end{array}
  \right.
}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \twopartdef{\{ \alpha \}}{x > 10}{\{ \beta \}}
\]
\end{document}
​
```

You have a `\arraycolsep` gap between the extensible left brace and the start of your "two part definition". If you want to remove that, use the `array` column specification `{@{}ll}`. Also, I've used `\right.` (not just `\right`) to end off the extensible brace pair.

[`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides a `cases` environment that does something similar. Here's your definition using that:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\twopartdef}[3]{%
  \begin{cases}
    #1 & \text{if #2} \\
    #3 & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x) = \twopartdef{\{ \alpha \}}{$x > 10$}{\{ \beta \}}
\]
\end{document}
```

For completeness, the entire condition is set in `\text`, which requires you to wrap `x>10`
in math mode again.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Also, I was aware of the second solution you suggested, just wanted to understand why it wasn't working.